# How can I recursively print a list of files with filenames shorter than 25 characters using a one-liner?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, command

I need a one line command for the below requirement.

Search all the files from the root directory and print only those files names whose file name length is less than 25.

I suppose we can do it with find command something like below:

`find / -type f |xargs basename ....` I am not sure about furthur command.

Comment: Please edit your question title to be more specific.

Comment: "A one line command" is an odd requirement.

Comment: No, I meant specific regarding what you want the command to *do*. Question titles should reflect the subject of the question and not be generic. I'll edit it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring quickly some manuals i got to find awk to be more suitable and easy to understand.please see the below solution which i had came up with.

```
find / -type f|awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'| awk 'length($0) < 25'
```

may be there are some syntax errors.please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That looks at the length of the whole path and filename, but it looks like a good start.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -type f|egrep "/[^/]{0,24}$"
```

Alternatively if you only want to display the filename without the path:

```
find / -type f| egrep -o "/[^/]{0,24}$" | cut -c 2-
```

Comment: This will find all files *in* the root directory, I suspect his "from" the root directory means recursively. If you want root directory only, it's quicker to pass -maxdepth 1 to find.

Comment: @Erik This will find the files recursively, and it will only match the filename. '^/[^/]{0,24}$' would only find the files _in_ the root directory. But correct me if I am wrong, also, thanks for the -maxdepth tip, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, my mind placed a ^ there. +1 for me being wrong.

Answer (score 2):

My GNU find supports this, unsure whether it's a part of standard find.

```
find / -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/.{1,24}$'
```

Alternatively, use find | grep.

```
find / -type f | egrep '.*/.{1,24}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*
do
   file=${file##*/}
   if (( ${#file} < 25 ));then echo "$file"; fi
done
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'Dir["**/*"].each {|x| puts x if File.basename(x).size < 25}'
```