# Command to list all file types and their average size in a directory

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I am working on a specific project where I need to work out the make-up of a large extract of documents so that we have a baseline for performance testing.

Specifically, I need a command that can recursively go through a directory and, for each file type, inform me of the number of files of that type and their average size.

I've looked at solutions like:
[Unix find average file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195493/unix-find-average-file-size),
[How can I recursively print a list of files with filenames shorter than 25 characters using a one-liner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050088/how-can-i-recursively-print-a-list-of-files-with-filenames-shorter-than-25-chara) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/compute-average-file-size, but nothing quite gets me to what I'm after.

Comment: So you mean to say nothing does _exactly what you want_ and that somebody should cook up something for you?

Comment: did your system support this command `stat --format="%s" FILE`, which will give you the file size directly.

Comment: @devnull Ok, maybe I phrased that badly. I don't know _how_ to get where I need to be. Pointers would be welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by file types, will extension be fine?

Comment: @anubhava Extension would be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This du and awk combination should work for you:

```
du -a mydir/ | awk -F'[.[:space:]]' '/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/ { a[$NF]+=$1; b[$NF]++ }
     END{for (i in a) print i, b[i], (a[i]/b[i])}'
```

Comment: Thanks, works brilliantly! One small change though, I've changed the `-a` switch to `-ak` because of the weird default block size on the `du` command.

Answer (score 2):

Give you something to start, with below script, you will get a list of file and its size, line by line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR=ABC
cd $DIR

find . -type f |while read line
do 
  # size=$(stat --format="%s" $line)    # For the system with stat command
  size=$(perl -e 'print -s $ARGV[0],"\n"' $line )  # @Mark Setchell provided the command, but I have no osx system to test it. 
  echo $size $line 
done
```

Output sample

```
123 ./a.txt
23 ./fds/afdsf.jpg
```

Then it is your homework, with above output, you should be easy to get file type and their average size

Comment: On OSX this gives a `stat: illegal option -- -`. I was kind of hoping that there might be a more succinct way of grouping find results though, but I'll go ahead and write a shell script. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You can use this little bit of Perl one-liner to get filesize on OSX in place of stat... perl -e 'print -s $ARGV[0],"\n"' somefile

Comment: Thanks, I added your recommend into my script.

Comment: It seems OSX does have a built-in stat, but the way it works is odd. The following gives the size of file "fred" in bytes:   stat -f "%Dz" fred

Answer (score 0):

You can use "du" maybe:

```
du -a -c *.txt
```

Sample output:

```
104 M1.txt
8   in.txt
8   keys.txt
8   text.txt
8   wordle.txt
136 total
```

The output is in 512-byte blocks, but you can change it with "-k" or "-m".